# SQL: List of the first letters of column value?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have keywords in table (for example `texts` table, `key` column). How to get list of first letters of keys ?

```
      key
[b]utton.upload
[b]utton.upload_file
[c]ontent.policy
[d]ontent.policy
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

[SUBSTRING (my_column, 1, 1)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx)

or

[SELECT LEFT(my_column,1)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous response.

But for the full query:

SELECT substring(key,1,1) AS FirstLetter FROM texts

Frank